# Failed to run custom step with the selenium cucumber ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, automated-tests

I am writing a test for desktop web automation using the
[selenium cucumber ruby](http://seleniumcucumber.info/desktop/).
My test includes both predefined and custom steps.

However, my test fails to run due to an error caused by a custom step.

**The feature file that I run:**

```
Feature: Login a customer
    Scenario: Go in a call
        Given I navigate to <url>
                  ...
        When I submit the form with id "custSearchSimple"
        ....
        And I wait for 5 sec
        Then element having id "accNumber" should be present
```

**The *When I submit the form with id "custSearchSimple"* is a custom step.**
This step is defined in the custom_step.rb. I have used the submit command of the [Selenium Cucumber Ruby API](https://github.com/selenium-cucumber/selenium-cucumber-ruby/blob/master/doc/selenium-cucumber-API.md). The custom_step.rb is the following file:

```
    require 'selenium-cucumber'

    # Do Not Remove This File
    # Add your custom steps here
    # $driver is instance of webdriver use this instance to write your custom code

   #firefox browser instantiation
   driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
   driver.navigate.to "https://localhost/telebet"

    When(/^I submit the form with id "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
         element= driver.submit(:id,"#{arg1}")
    end
```

When I run the feature file by running cucumber features/name_of_the_file.feature, I get the NoMethodError error:

```
When I submit the form with id "custSearchSimple"                 # features/step_definitions/custom_steps.rb:12
  private method `submit' called for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x94c4bde4bdff4d6 browser=:firefox> (NoMethodError)
```

I could not find any example using the Selenium Cucumber Ruby API for writing custom steps. I suspect that I might have omitted some commands for the selenium web driver ruby. Something is missing that I could not find. Does anyone know why I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am confused here but:

```
When(/^I submit the form with id "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  submit_form arg1
end

def submit_form(form_id)
  submit("id", form_id)
end
```

Would do what you want? `submit_form` isn't a cucumber step, it's a ruby method - probably why you're getting `Cucumber::UndefinedDynamicStep`.

Comment: Yes, exactly the submit is a ruby function.
Sorry, I recently realized that I should use the selenium webdriver for calling the submit ruby function. I just updated my post.
Now, I get the NoMethodError error.

Comment: You're trying to call `submit` on your browser object, not on a form/`Selenium::WebDriver::Element`. You need to find your form first by doing something like `form = driver.find_element(id: form_id)` and then `form.submit`. See if that helps.